# Duda con Array.prototype.forEach.call

Tags: javascript

quería saber que hace exactamente Array.prototype.forEach.call en el siguiente fragmento de código, es decir, creo que devolvería un array pero a su vez, la variable "opcion" también devolvería un array ¿no?. Si alguien me pudiera explicar como funciona y de que manera afecta al código se lo agradecería.

```js
         let opcion = document.getElementsByClassName('opcion');

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(opcion, function (e) {
            e.addEventListener('click', function () {
                if (e.innerHTML === "Click me") {
                    e.innerHTML = "Clicked";
                } else {
                    e.innerHTML = "Click me";
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
        div {
        background: blue;
        }
        
        h1 {
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="opcion">Click me</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="opcion">Click me</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="opcion">Click me</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="opcion">Click me</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="opcion">Click me</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` regresa un arreglo con los elementos que tengan la clase que se desea. `forEach` lo que hace es simplemente iterar el arreglo que se pasa como parametro, y ya es decision del programador lo que se quiera hacer con cada elemento del arreglo. Te dejo un link a la docuentacion de `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez te contradices en tu comentario, esto: `document.getElementsByClassName('.opcion');` tampoco devuelve un Array, por lo tanto no puedes usar directamente `forEach`. Además, el argumento que espera recibir ese método es una cadena que representa el nombre de la clase, esto: `'.opcion'` sería un nombre de clase inválido (ver [documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)). Te recomiendo que elimines tu comentario ya que no es correcto lo que indicas. Saludos

Comment: Para saber exactamente lo que hace `Array.prototype.call`, una lectura al tema [Function call](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) no está demás. Tal como te han comentado, el método `getElementsByClassName` no devuelve un Array, sino un Objeto llamado `HTMLCollection`, que es iterable como un Array, pero que no hereda los métodos del Objeto Array. Al ser iterable, podemos aplicar métodos de Array mediante `call` sobre dicho objeto. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por la aclaración, pensé que había escrito un `querySelector` que aunque tampoco es un array, pues sí tiene el método forEach. Gracias por la aclaración, supongo no revisé bien mi comentario y copié y pegué sin cambiar el método.

Comment: @Jaime creo que tienes una confusión entre `querySelector` y `querySelectorAll`. El primero devuelve el primer elemento que coincida con la búsqueda y el segundo devuelve una [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que efectivamente implementa `forEach`. Saludos

Comment: Definitivamente debo revisar lo que escribo porque no se corresponde con lo que tengo en la cabeza. Tienes toda la razón. Gracias @MauricioContreras

Comment: Hola, gracias por las aclaraciones, aunque aún me queda una duda. Según he leído Array.prototype es el "objeto padre", entonces, ¿de qué manera actúa en esa función? ¿Se crearía un array al usar Array.prototype?